# How to change the site title font style in wordpress theme Bizberg Consulting Dark

Tags: css, wordpress, webfonts

hello guys av been trying to change the font family/ font style of this WordPress theme **Bizberg Consulting Dark** for days now, I have looked for this on all the theme editor files but could not find the solution when I inspected the theme on chrome the front family is currently on

```
.primary_header_2 h3, .bizberg_header_wrapper h3 {
    font-family: Dancing Script;
   }
```

I also tried changing this using the additional CSS option on WordPress but any input I give it doesn't work, but when I try

```
.primary_header_2 h3, .bizberg_header_wrapper h3 {
    display: none;}
```

The whole of the site title disappears showing that this id is the correct id for this change but when I try to input another type of font-family it doesn't work I have looked for this on all the theme editor files but could not find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your additional css option in wordpress after the css you should input !important and this will overide all functions the theme is playinging initially eg

```
.header_site_title {
     font-family: Times New Roman !important; 
}
```

Comment: thanks alot i just tried it now and it worked perfectly as you just described i really appreciate this